# setAccelerator for jmenu item in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm learning java with Swing. I have a problem with setAccelerator for menu.
My code:

```
    closeItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    closeOtherItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
    KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK&ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
```

I want when I press Ctrl+W, my JTabbedPane will close selectedTab, and when press Ctrl+Shift+W my JtabbedPane will close all ignore selectedTab. But only action Ctrl+W was detected, although when I click on closeOtherItem my program will run normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try or'ing the modifers instead of and'ing and use `InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK` and `InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` instead...

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 
                       InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)
```